# How do Relativity explains electromagnetic induction in the case of changing $\bf{B}$ with both loop and magnet at rest?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Here is how *Griffiths* lists the experimental evidences of electromagnetic induction.

[image]

Case 1 can be explained with Lorentz Force. I understood how Special Relativity relates case 2 to case 1, predicting the presence of an electric field in the frame of reference of the circuit, in place of what Lorentz Force would have created.

Nevertheless I do not see how Special Relativity relates case 3 to the other two: roughly speaking there is "nothing moving" in case 3, so how do I use Lorentz transformations of fields?

It can be said that, from the point of view of the loop, case 3 is just equal to case 2 since in both cases the magnetic field is changing and that's it. But I would like to know if there is a different way by which the transformation of fields relates case 3 to case 1.

In other words, do trasformations of fields predicts that, in case 3 an electric field will appear because of the changing magnetic field? If so, how do it predict that?

Comment: I think the question is " in the 3rd case, how the electromagnetic induction can be explained using relativity (and electrostatic equation) as is done in the case 1 and case 2. If we can find the answer to this question, new way of thinking about the phenomeno of electromagnetic inductance may be appear, it is not the phenomena given by the heaven but it is the resulting one give by the relativity and electrostatic equation. The point is " How relativity explaines induction in the case of case of changing B with both electrical loop is at rest (fixed or does not move)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need relativity to analyze the third case: all the causal actors in this scene are in the same inertial frame. Here it is simply a case of applying Faraday's law in its wonted for $\nabla\times\vec{E}=-\partial_t\,\vec{B}$.

However, relativity is tied in with this problem insofar that Maxwell's equations are of course covariant with respect to the Lorentz transformation. Therefore, you could realize an equivalent effect by shifting a graded magnetic field relative to the loop (as happens in an AC induction motor, for example), making it equivalent to case (b) and you'd get the same answer for the EMF around the loop.